# Openpyxl NamedStyle isn't applying alignment to excel cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to write data into excel files. I defined a function `create_style` to create named styles by passing a name and font, alignment, border styles etc. Once a style is created it'll be added to workbook and can be used anytime. In my case, `NamedStyle` is setting the `alignment` attributes to `None`. However, fonts,fills are working fine.  I couldn't figure the problem.
 Here's the code.

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font, NamedStyle

# to create a style passing workbook, name and optional arguments like font etc
def create_style(wb,stylename,**kwargs):
    if stylename not in wb.named_styles:
        style = NamedStyle(name=stylename)
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            if value is not None:
                setattr(style,key,value)
        wb.add_named_style(style)


excelpath = '/path/to/my/master-excel-file.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(excelpath) if os.path.isfile(excelpath) else Workbook()

sheetname = 'sheet1'
sheets = workbook.get_sheet_names()
if sheetname in sheets:
    print('loading existing sheet')
    worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
else:
    print('creating sheet...')
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(sheetname)

font_1 = Font(name='Arial', size=18)

alignment_1 = Alignment(horizontal='general',
                vertical='center')

create_style(workbook,'style1',font=font_1,alignment=alignment_1)

workbook.save(excelpath)

# My doubt is here
print(workbook._named_styles['style1'].font)
print('\n')
print(workbook._named_styles['style1'].alignment)
```

Let's assume there's no excel file in the path, then the code will create new excel file and create 'style1' and saves it in the workbook.

output1 :

```
creating sheet...
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name='Arial', charset=None, family=None, b=False, i=False, strike=None, 
outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=None, extend=None, sz=18.0, 
u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None


<openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment object>
Parameters:
horizontal='general', vertical='center', textRotation=0, wrapText=None, 
shrinkToFit=None, indent=0.0, relativeIndent=0.0, justifyLastLine=None, 
readingOrder=0.0
```

When I run the same code again, `None` is assigned to all `alignment` parameters.

output 2:

```
loading existing sheet
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name='Arial', charset=None, family=None, b=False, i=False, strike=None, 
outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=None, extend=None, sz=18.0, 
u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None


<openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment object>
Parameters:
horizontal=None, vertical=None, textRotation=0, wrapText=None, 
shrinkToFit=None, indent=0.0, relativeIndent=0.0, justifyLastLine=None, 
readingOrder=0.0
```

which means the `style1` losing data regarding alignment on every run while `font` is working just fine. In other words, `style1` isn't retaining the `alignment`. Why is it happening ?

Comment: If you think there is a bug then you should submit a bug report to the openpyxl bug tracker.

Comment: Only the `fill` and `font`  retain the user given values when a style is loaded. `alignment` and  `protection` are defaulted to the respective values of `Normal` named style. I don't think it's an expected behavior, can be a bug.